# Which mobile/computer application can help me understand celestial coordinate systems better?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, coordinate

I wish to understand Equatorial and Altazimuth coordinate systems much better. Any applications or softwares which can help me out with the same?

Comment: There's a lot of videos on Youtube.  It would help if you explained what it is about them you're having issues with.

Comment: https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-resources/right-ascension-declination-celestial-coordinates/

Answer (score 1):

There is a course about positional astronomy at the universtity of St. Andrews in Scotland with a lot of nice drawings and questions and answers.
The url is: http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/%7Efv/webnotes/intro.htm
Kind Regards
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Use http://stellarium.org, you can change the view and see the differences between systems

Comment: I like Stellarium too, but could you edit your answer to say more about how to use it for that purpose?